# Export stereo camera .chan

Tags: export

How to export a stereo camera in .chan file format ? 
I use a option Stereo 3D in RenderLayer pannel. I can't switch camera left or right for export. There is not option in export settings. Do you have a trick ?

Comment: Never seen a stereo `.chan` file. Can you post an example?

Comment: i would like a .chan for the left camera and a other .chan file for the right. The objective is import two .chan files in Nuke. Below an example : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4721466/BLENDER/StereoTest.blend

Comment: I don't select the left and right camera because this is a same object.

Comment: UP ! I don't find solution. I can't apply "Cameras"  button. Even with bake, i have a single object. Nobody have a trick ?